# missing LibSVM wrapper in weka 3.8 in "java code" (I have already installed it and can see it in the experimenter)

Tags: java, eclipse, weka

I am using eclipse and java code. Trying to use LibSVM in weka.

There used to be a wrapper in "weka.classifiers.functions" package for LibSVM in weka 3.6. Now that I am using weka 3.8, there is no such wrapper in that package.

I can "successfully" use it when I rollback to weka 3.6. So I have correctly set up the additional jar file of libsv and the class path.

In weka 3.8, I have also installed the libsvm wrapper using package manager, and can use it in the experimenter. But it looks the only problem is that there is no such wrapper in the java code.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:
It has been removed.
We need to use the GUI to install the wrapper separately, then find the path to the directory which it installs the packages in, and import it into eclipse.